# image preview on html video

Tags: php, jquery, html

hello I want to build a video web site, where the videos once you pass your mouse over the progress bar you could see a image preview of the video you are watching like youtube for example , so I want to know please what is the better way to do this on php and jquery.

Comment: What did you try? Do you expect someone code it without any effort from you?

Comment: of course not but do you even know me? sorry but not

Answer (score 0):

There are some out-of-the-box alternatives, like [JWPlayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/). It's very flexible there's an example of what you're trying to do [here](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1407439-adding-).